# DPKG lock-frontend file issue

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, dpkg, tor

Ok So I am trying to install tor browser by commands

```
apt-get install tor torbrowser-launcher
```

also tried
sudo apt-get install tor torbrowser-launcher

but The error I am getting is

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Actually before this I was getting some other errors from dpkg which denied me permissions.
So I ran some commands to remove some 3 lock files but I also removed lock-frontend after that.
It was written in some article.
So what should I do now?

Comment: I tried that but problem still remains the same

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: If you re-read first or second answer, you may conclude that you need to run `apt-get` commands with elevated privileges, i.e., with `sudo`. Try running `sudo apt-get install tor torbrowser-launcher`.

Comment: thanks sudo command is working now, i don't know what mistake i was doing earlier with that command but now it is working.

Comment: by the way, do I need to change anything in dpkg? Is there any mistake I made there I need to correct

Comment: Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. is this an issue?